# ¿Cómo validar la longitud de un decimal en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, string, numberformat

Tengo una variable con la siguiente info:

```
123.43
```

¿Cómo podría saber la longitud de los decimales? Es decir, recibir una respuesta de carácter numérico, como por ejemplo: 2, en el caso de la variable de arriba.

Comment: Bienvenido letotole a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Que tipo de dato es el que vas a chequear `decimal`, `float`?

Answer (score 2):

Si los números son float puedes hacerlo así. Convertir el número a varchar, buscar la primera vez aparición de la parte decimal, y restarla de esta.

```
declare @float float;

select @float = 123.43

select 
LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@float,128))  AS LongFloat,
CHARINDEX('.',(cast(@float as varchar(20))),1) AS sobraFloat,
LEN(CONVERt(VARCHAR(50),@float,128)) - CHARINDEX('.',(cast(@float as varchar(20))),1) AS DecimalesFloat
```

Si son de otro tipo de dato, tendrás que precisar la información.

[image: Resultado]